# How to remove apache information completely from response headers

Tags: apache

In Apache configuration, the server sends HTTP Header with the Apache information.

After googling, I found that this information can be controlled by setting ServerTokens and ServerSignature directives.

"ServerTokens prod" will show only 'Apache' in the response header.

Is there a way to hide even 'Apache' word from the header?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: Our security team asked us to remove any product related information from the header. So I wanted to know if it is even possible?

Comment: try below: 
Header always unset "server"
Header unset "server"

Answer (score 2):

I'll give the example how to solve that on centos7 OS.

1. Add the EPEL rpm:

   ```
   # rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/e/epel-release-7-11.noarch.rpm
   ```
2. Install the mod_security:

   ```
   yum install mod_security mod_security_crs
   ```

3.Go to mod_security.conf file and edit that

4. Eraser all the instructions inside the "ifModule" and add the **SecServerSignature " "** instruction inside the "ifModule"
5. restart the server

[image]

[image]