# How to remove HTTP Server "Apache"?

Tags: apache, http-headers, server

For security reason, i need remove(yes!, really I need remove, delete or hide) Apache signature.

I use ServerSignature n' ServerTokens directives, but only hide the version...

```
ServerSignature Off
ServerTokens Prod
```

The results is:

```
Name                :Value
Date                :Mon, 15 Jun 2015 11:47:28 GMT
Content-Encoding    :gzip
Last-Modified       :Sun, 14 Jun 2015 00:01:37 GMT
Server              :Apache
ETag                :"6176c-28f4-5186f0b8c3bb0"
Vary                :Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Content-Type        :text/xml; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control       :max-age=1
Accept-Ranges       :bytes
Content-Length      :1531
Expires             :Mon, 15 Jun 2015 11:47:29 GMT
```

Look this

```
Server              Apache
```

I need(without http header "Server:Apache"):

```
Name                Value
Date                Mon, 15 Jun 2015 11:47:28 GMT
Content-Encoding    gzip
Last-Modified       Sun, 14 Jun 2015 00:01:37 GMT
ETag                "6176c-28f4-5186f0b8c3bb0"
Vary                Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Content-Type        text/xml; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control       max-age=1
Accept-Ranges       bytes
Content-Length      1531
Expires             Mon, 15 Jun 2015 11:47:29 GMT
```

Thanks!

> I am very sorry Apache team, but this time can't show your
>   signature.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove Server: Apache from response headers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25804911/remove-server-apache-from-response-headers)

Comment: This issue was resolved on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20803348/how-to-remove-apache-information-completely-from-response-headers/54634628#54634628

Comment: Please check the link below:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20803348/how-to-remove-apache-information-completely-from-response-headers/54634628#54634628

Answer (score 0):

The core distribution doesn't allow it to be removed. It's trivial to do in a plugin. mod_security allows you to configure it to be stripped.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment, but it's a bit long....

`For security reason, i need remove...Apache signature` - even from the data *other* than the Server header it is blatantly obvious that this is an Apache server (or something doing a *very* good impression of one).

As per discussion on [security.stackexchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/23256/what-is-the-http-server-response-header-field-used-for) I do not believe that there is any security benefit in removing banners from your software. In addition to the information in your headers I could also determine this from the default error messages, how the server handles content negotiation, conditional requests, .... every time I look at a related issue, the list gets longer.

I've yet to see *any* evidence that disabling banners had any impact on a sites security (as opposed to allowing an auditor to tick a box in a checklist). But if anyone can provide a reference I would be very interested to hear.